# Restore DB from MDF file, lost LDF and DB was not cleanly shutdown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, mdf

My dev DB server was formatted by some admin without my knowledge. Thankfully I had .mdf file kept in some other drive but .ldf was in its default location. Since I don’t have DB backup I am now left with .mdf file. I googled and found various tricks to restore DB from .mdf file. Since database was not cleanly shutdown none of the tricks worked. I have SQL Server 2008 SP2 installed in my machine. As I remember lost DB server was SQL Server 2005 instance. Please let me know how I could recover my database.

Tricks i tried:

1. I tried to attach the .mdf from SSMS by removing the log file item from database to attach list.
2. `CREATE DATABASE Monitoring ON (FILENAME = N'D:\Dump\Data\Monitoring.MDF') FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`
3. `sp_attach_single_file_db N'Monitoring', N'D:\Dump\Data\Monitoring_Data.MDF'`

In all above I got

> Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options.

Then I tried `DBCC REBUILD_LOG('Monitoring',N'C:\Program Files ..MSSQL\Data\Monitoring_log.ldf')` which resulted in:

> Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options.” error.

Comment: IMO you need some 3rd party sql/mdf recovery tool. I've yet to see any always usable hint or trick, allowing to recover such mdf file with SQL options only. I've even modified mdf file in hex editor to change ldf location (to point it to clean ldf); no success.

Comment: You will get a better answer on the dba site than here, but you will have to include the "tricks" you already tried and what the result of each one was (e.g. the specific error messages).

Comment: 1. I tried to attach the mdf from SSMS by removing the log file item from database to attach list.
2. CREATE DATABASE Monitoring ON (FILENAME = N'D:\Dump\Data\Monitoring.MDF') FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
3. sp_attach_single_file_db N'Monitoring', N'D:\Dump\Data\Monitoring_Data.MDF' 
In all above I got “Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options.”
Then I tried  DBCC REBUILD_LOG('Monitoring',N'C:\Program Files ..MSSQL\Data\Monitoring_log.ldf') which resulted in “Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options."

Comment: Same question on DBA SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15940

Answer (score 2):

Here are some notes (for SQL 2000) that might help. I've never tried these personally.

1. In EM create a DB with the same name as the original.
2. Stop the SQL service (instance).
3. Copy the old .MDF over the new one.
4. Start the service (instance).
5. DB will appear as suspect in EM.
6. Fire up Query Manager.
7. Connect to the running instance.
8. Put the DB into Emergency Bypass Status by doing the following:

   ```
   sp_configure 'allow', 1 
   go 
   reconfigure with overide. 

   update master..sysdatabases 
   set status=32768 
   where dbid=5    --check this ID is for your db
   ```
9. Stop the SQL service (instance).
10. Delete the LDF.
11. Start the SQL service (instance).
12. Execute the following in QM:

    ```
    select dbid, status, name 
    from master..sysdatabases 
    dbcc rebuild_log ('dbname', 'full path and LDF name')
    ```
13. Revert DB from Emergency Bypass Status by executng in QM:

    ```
     update master..sysdatabases 
     set status=16 
     where dbid=5 --Check this ID for your db
    ```
14. Cleanup by executing the following in QM:

    ```
     sp_configure 'allow', 0 
     go 
     reconfigure with override
    ```

Comment: "dbcc rebuild_log" is not supported in SQL Server 2008. I got "Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options." message.

Comment: Yes, its implemented by `ALTER DATABASE` statement now: `ALTER DATABASE dbname REBUILD LOG ON (NAME=dbname_Log,FILENAME='full path and LDF name')`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

ALTER DATABASE EmpDataBase REBUILD LOG ON (NAME=$DatabaseName$,FILENAME=N'$Path\DatabaseName.ldf$')

GO

DBCC CHECKDB

ALTER DATABASE $DatabaseName$ SET MULTI_USER

GO